# Pandas split string on matching substring from list

Tags: pandas, list, split

I have not been able to find an answer to the question how to split strings in rows that have substrings matching values in a list (not a part of the dataframe). In other words, I need to split/extract the substrings that match any of the values in a dynamic list from a Series rows. There are many answers on how to mark such rows as True/False or how to split on a match to a static list, but I am stuck at trying to combine both tasks in one. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Example:
Series - Mr. John Doe, Ms. Jane Smith, Dr. Who, Dr. No, Doctor Doolittle, Mister X, Batman
List 1 - Dr., Doctor

Output - Mr. John Doe, Ms. Jane Smith, Who, No, Doolittle, Mister X, Batman

List 2 - Mr, Mister

Output - John Doe, Ms. Jane Smith, Dr. Who, Dr. No, Doctor Doolittle, X, Batman

Comment: Could you please include a minimal data set, as well as your desired output to your post?

Comment: @rahlf23 - I've just added two simple examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = pd.Series('Mr. John Doe, Ms. Jane Smith, Dr. Who, Dr. No, Doctor Doolittle, Mister X, Batman'.split(', '))
```

```
l = ['Dr. ', 'Doctor ']
list(s.str.replace('({})'.format('|'.join(l)), ''))

Out:
['Mr. John Doe',
 'Ms. Jane Smith',
 'Who',
 'No',
 'Doolittle',
 'Mister X',
 'Batman']
```

```
l = ['Mr. ', 'Mister ']
list(s.str.replace('({})'.format('|'.join(l)), ''))

Out:
['John Doe',
 'Ms. Jane Smith',
 'Dr. Who',
 'Dr. No',
 'Doctor Doolittle',
 'X',
 'Batman']
```

Comment: Terrific. Thank you. There had to be something elegant to solve this. There is a practical issue with this solution, however. It only picks the first value from a list. I.e., if there's a 'Mr' and a 'Mrs' in the list example above, than this solution will pick Mr and output the value 's. Doubtfire' for 'Mrs. Doubtfire' row entry.

Comment: If the strings in the `l` list include the following spaces (such as 'Mr.`[space]`') it shouldn't be a problem. For example, if I have `l = ['Mrs. ', 'Mr. ', 'Mister ']` and I add `'Mrs. Doubtfire'` to the original list, it works correctly, removing all of the items from `l` (so the output is `['John Doe',  'Ms. Jane Smith', 'Dr. Who', 'Dr. No', 'Doctor Doolittle', 'X', 'Batman', 'Doubtfire']`)

Comment: Indeed, that would work, but, unfortunately, I have no power over the list entries. Some of the entries are the similar except for the period at the end. But thank you anyway for a very practical solution that will work in many other, less esoteric, circumstances.

Comment: One more thing that may possibly help is placing the longer matching string first, e.g.: `pd.Series(['MrJohnDoe', 'MrsDoubtfire']).str.replace('(Mr|Mrs)', '')` results in `['JohnDoe', 'sDoubtfire']`, but `pd.Series(['MrJohnDoe', 'MrsDoubtfire']).str.replace('(Mrs|Mr)', '')` does the right thing `['JohnDoe', 'Doubtfire']`

Comment: And, by the way, it's all regular expressions, so you can even combine Mr/Mrs/Mr./... into one pattern, for example: `pd.Series(['MrJohnDoe', 'Mr. John Doe', 'MrsDoubtfire', 'Mrs.Jane Smith']).str.replace('Mr(s)?(\.)?(\s)?', '')` will output `['JohnDoe', 'John Doe', 'Doubtfire', 'Jane Smith']`

Comment: I have a 314 item list, so combining them in a single regex may be a bit of a challenge.. :)

Comment: Oh, that would likely take some effort :) I think I would just start with sorting the list `l` by the length of the string in reverse order to have longer matches earlier in the list, so that `Mrs` is removed before `Mr` etc. There still may be some cases where it doesn't work, but at least that would probably be a good starting point

Comment: That's a very good idea. There are definitely some caveats, but I shall try. I'll update on the results when I get there.